# Adding element to a list in class, which is a part of List<class>, based on condition

Tags: c#

Let's have a simple class with 2 fields

```
public class Sample
{
    public int IdOfSample;
    public string SampleName;
}
```

And another using this one

```
public class ListOfSamples
{
    public int IdOfList;
    public List<Sample> SampleList;
}
```

And finally, since we will use a couple of different ListOfSamples, make a list of them:

```
public static List<ListOfSamples> FinalList = new List<ListOfSamples>();
```

Now the problem:

I create a new `Sample` (let's call it `NewItem`), with some name and Id. I want to check if there's a `ListOfSamples` in my `FinalList` that as the same Id as the NewItem I have. Otherwise create new `ListOfSamples` in the `FinalList` with the `IdOfList = NewItem.IdOfSample`.

I think I got the first part which checks if you should add a new list (ie. a `ListOfSamples` with specified `IdOfList` does not exist:

```
Sample NewItem = new Sample()
{
    IdOfSample = 12345,
    SampleName = "Some name"
};

int index = FinalList.FindIndex(f => f.IdOfList == NewItem.IdOfSample);

if (!FinalList.Any() || index == -1)
{
    ListOfSamples NewList = new ListOfSamples()
    {
        IdOfList = NewItem.IdOfSample,
        SampleList = new List<Sample>()
    };
    NewList.SampleList.Add(NewItem);
    FinalList.Add(NewList);
}
```

Now, I'm trying to construct a statement, that, if the list with specified Id already exists in the `FinalList`, just add the new item to it, but so far I think my limited experience with LINQ is showing, nothing I try seems to work.

So:

If there exists a `ListOfSamples` with `IdOfList == NewItem.IdOfSample` in `FinalList`, then add `NewItem` to that `ListOfSamples`.

Comment: Instead of `ListOfSamples` it sounds like you actually want a `Dictionary<int, List<Sample>` that way your lookup on the id will be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
if (!FinalList.Any() || index == -1)
    ...
else
{
    FinalList[index].SampleList.Add(NewItem);
}
```

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of `FinalList[index]` type of statement, will check it out. Edit: It just werks, thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

If you just wanted to check whether the list item existed, a suitable LINQ statement could be:

```
if (FinalList.Any(l => l.IdOfList == NewItem.IdOfSample))
{
   // ...
}
```

Given you want to work on the item then you could attempt to retrieve it as follows:

```
var existingList = FinalList.SingleOrDefault(l => l.IdOfList == NewItem.IdOfSample);
if (existingList != null)
{
   existingList.Add( ... );
}
```

Though perhaps it's worth thinking about using a HashSet of lists if you want to guarantee uniqueness...

Answer (score 1):

If you replace `ListOfSamples` with a `Dictionary<int, List<Sample>>` then you will gain the ability to do a lookup in O(1) time and guarantee that the ids at the top level are unique. and then you can just add stuff like this.

```
Dictionary<int, List<Sample>> FinalList = new Dictionary<int, List<Sample>>();

Sample NewItem = new Sample()
{
    IdOfSample = 12345,
    SampleName = "Some name"
};

List<Sample> list;
if (!FinalList.TryGetValue(NewItem.IdOfSample, out list))
{
    list = new List<Sample>();
    FinalList.Add(NewItem.IdOfSample, list);
}

list.Add(NewItem);
```

`TryGetValue` will see if the dictionary has an entry for the key you pass it and returns `true` if it does and `false` if it does not.  If it does have an entry for the key it also assigns the value of the entry (in this case your list of samples) to the `out` parameter.  So, we check if it returns `false` and in that case we create a new list and add it to the dictionary.  Then we add the sample to the list that we either got from the dictionary, or just created and put in the dictionary.

Comment: I never used `Dictionary` but thank you for your answer, will look into it and try using it. +1 for nice example.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand it right ...

```
// search for the list with the given Id
var listOfSamples = finalList.Where(fl => fl.IdOfList == newItem.IdOfSample).FirstOrDefault();

if (listOfSamples == null)
{
    // not found
    // add new List with the new item in final list
    finalList.Add(new ListOfSamples {IdOfList = newItem.IdOfSample, SampleList = new List<Sample>{newItem}} );
}
else
{
    // found
    // add the new item into the found list
    listOfSamples.SampleList.Add(newItem);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add the `newItem` to the `SampleList` in the new `ListOfSamples` you created when you don't find a match in the `finalList`.